# Горизонтальное расположение верхнего меню в joomla

Tags: меню, joomla

[На сайте](http://foto.skynet-centr.com) никак не получается сделать верхнее меню горизонтальным. Так же заметил, что в [демо шаблоне](http://demo.rockettheme.com/joomla25/fracture/) есть позиция [*menu*](http://demo.rockettheme.com/joomla25/fracture/?tp=1), в которой располагается меню, но которой нет на моем [сайте.](http://foto.skynet-centr.com/?tp=1). Как можно решить данную проблему?
P.S.: версия joomla 2.5.8

Comment: Разве никто не знает?

Comment: Уважаемые программисты, пожалуйста, помогите с данным вопросом

Comment: float: left на li  и ul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эта проблема решается путем редактирования **css** файла. Как именно знаете или это тоже следует объяснить?

Comment: Если не сложно, просьба объяснить. Просто раньше просто это было в настройках joomla (так же часто эту надстройку делают в настройках шаблона).